# HtmlUnit Javascript: Cannot read property "style" from null

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I have a problem using HtmlUnit.
I think the website contains some wrong javascript code which isn't a problem for the Firefox or Chrome but for HtmlUnit.

When I execute the Java code from below it throws the exception I also mentioned down below.

I've already tried:

> client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
>   client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

Well it worked, I didn't get an exception anymore but I couldn't execute any javascript code anymore.

> page.executeJavaScript(javaScriptCode)

From now on every javascript request result in an useless value or didn't even made changes to the page.

I just want to execute my Java code without getting an exception.
I hope somebody is able to help me.

***My Java code***

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    HtmlPage page = client.getPage("xxx");
```

***Part of the javascript code from the webpage***

```
function checkDeptLogin() {
        if (logintextboxvalidate == "_Dept_login")
        {
            visibleaccount();
        }

        document.getElementById('leftcolmnmain').style.display = 'block'; //Line 168
        document.getElementById('stapleid').style.display = 'none';

        if (document.getElementById('postlstinfoid') != null)
        {
            document.getElementById('postlstinfoid').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

```
    document.write('<div id = "leftcolmnmain" style="display:none">'); //Line 1778
```

> EcmaError: lineNumber=[168] column=[0] lineSource=[null]
>   name=[TypeError] sourceName=[script in xxx/startwlm/Start_Wlm.htm from
>   (23, 54) to (223, 10)] message=[TypeError: Cannot read property
>   "style" from null (script in xxx/startwlm/Start_Wlm.htm from (23, 54)
>   to (223, 10)#168)] com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException:
>   TypeError: Cannot read property "style" from null (script in
>   xxx/startwlm/Start_Wlm.htm from (23, 54) to (223, 10)#168)

Comment: The error message means that whatever is to the left of `.style` is null, in this case one of the three `document.getElementById()` calls comes back blank.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the style of an element which is not yet inserted into the DOM. Consider accessing it after it's added.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure
document.write('');
runs before
document.getElementById('leftcolmnmain').style.display = 'block';
line of code, else it will throw exception as in your case, as 
document.getElementById('leftcolmnmain') 
will be null then.

Comment: I dont't really understand. What do I have to add to my code to make it work?

Comment: An how to influence that? It is not possible to edit the Javascript code from the web site

Comment: Apologies for delay response, hoping by now it would have got resolved. You could add the null check for safety and then verify.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the page (and being able to reproduce) i can give only some general hints:

- add webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false); to let the js engine continue after the error (like real browsers)
- add webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10_000); AFTER HtmlPage page = client.getPage("xxx"); to let the jsEngine do the whole (async) work before clicking

And finally why you click using js - you can trigger the click() directly from java/Htmlunit

Comment: Thanks.... but sadly it doesn't work. 
"HtmlPage page = client.getPage("xxx");" produces the failure, the lines below. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: Any chance to provide a small complete reproducable sample (maybe via private mail)?

Comment: This is a printer web overlay in a private network. Its not that easy. Would screenshots of the source code help?

Comment: Not really, but may be the source code of 'xxx/startwlm/Start_Wlm.htm' (at least if the js inside is not obfuscated
It will be cool if you can open a issue at github for this, makes it easier for me to track.

Comment: I would rather send you a private mail with the source code. On stackoverflow you cannot send private messages, can you? Can you give me your email address or something else to contact you?

Comment: You can find my private e-mail on the HtmlUnit homepage under developers